# No object or images found to bake to

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, baking, error

I tried to give a bake to make a texture from the selected object but it does not work. I've made a new image and you can even see it on the screenshot, image, .,Barrel.001" and tries to do it in UV editing or through the default layout selecting ,,tab'' and then ,,a'' to select the whole object but then I have the same error when I press bake.

[image]

Comment: Include screenshots into the question body please, so that they don't get lost after some time (which in your case will make question absolutely unclear). Regarding error - make sure there isn't any hidden geometry (Alt+H in Edit mode) which isn't assigned to texture (select it and once more select image in UV editor)

Answer (score -1):

it is kind of weird, but make sure the texture you bake to is present in your material node tree and make sure it is selected when you bake.

Comment: They use Blender Render engine which has different baking